# bulk item update using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Is there any way to update bulk list items using **REST API** in sharepoint online site.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint Online, the Rest API does support batch operations. If you are using PnP then things will become easier for you in this regard:

Sample from PnP Documentation: [Source](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/items/#update-multiple-items)

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";

let list = sp.web.lists.getByTitle("rapidupdate");

list.getListItemEntityTypeFullName().then(entityTypeFullName => {

    let batch = sp.web.createBatch();

    // note requirement of "*" eTag param - or use a specific eTag value as needed
    list.items.getById(1).inBatch(batch).update({ Title: "Batch 6" }, "*", entityTypeFullName).then(b => {
        console.log(b);
    });

    list.items.getById(2).inBatch(batch).update({ Title: "Batch 7" }, "*", entityTypeFullName).then(b => {
        console.log(b);
    });

    batch.execute().then(d => console.log("Done"));
});
```

Comment: Oh, wow, I had no idea PnP Js had batch operation. Thank you for posting it!

Comment: Stand alone batchutility is also there take a look https://github.com/anomepani/sp-rest-util/blob/master/BatchUtils.ts

Answer (score 2):

You can batch queries and operations against the REST/OData API of Microsoft SharePoint Online (and on-premises SharePoint 2016 and later) and the Files and folders subset of the Office 365 REST APIs.

The request URL consists of the root service URL and the `$batch` option.

For example:

```
https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com/_api/$batch
```

Or

```
https://fabrikam.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/$batch
```

**Reference**:

[Make batch requests with the REST APIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis).